# Iptables configuration

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have a **pptpd** service running on the VDS (ip: **212.109.XX.XX**).

My router connected to the internet via this **vpn (pptp)** so WAN IP is **212.109.XX.XX**

Also I have a **device** which working on **554** port (rtsp stream) with ip **192.168.1.33**

pptpd configured this way:

```
localip 192.168.0.234-238,192.168.0.245 

remoteip 192.168.2.234-238,192.168.2.245
```

so the router gets ip 192.168.2.234

I've configured router NAT settings this way: [NAT config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Owd2v.png) (the same with UDP)

I try to watch the stream from my computer (that connected to the router) with rtsp://192.168.2.234:554 and it works such as rtsp://192.168.1.33:554. But I need to watch it via **rtsp://212.109.XX.XX:554**

I think that I need to put something in iptables. I've tried several variants but nothing succeeded.

server iptables rules now is almost empty:

```
root@server:~# iptables -L -n -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0 



root@server:~# iptables -L 
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
TCPMSS     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:SYN,RST/SYN tcpmss match 800:1536 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Please help to find the way to connect to the device from internet via **rtsp://212.109.XX.XX:554**

Network diagram is about like this:

[image: this]

Comment: If the RTSP stream doesn't include the actual (usually) RTP streams inside (on the same port 554), NAT won't be enough, without changing the RTSP server configuration (if possible) or using a non mainline kernel iptables helper ( eg https://sources.debian.org/src/nat-rtsp/ from https://github.com/maru-sama/rtsp-linux   )

Comment: Warning: PPTP has been obsolete and broken for many years. You should not rely on it for privacy or confidentiality.